NextJS build error with typescript index signature
When I do pnpm run build I got this error:
✓ Compiled successfullyLinting and checking validity of types  ..Failed to compile. .next/types/app/components/button/addNew/page.ts:

Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<ButtonProps, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.Property 'onClick' is incompatible with index signature.Type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

// Check the prop type of the entry function
28 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()|             ^29 |30 | // Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function31 | if ('generateMetadata' in entry) { ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

my component page.tsx looks like this and is working well:
interface ButtonProps {onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;}

export default function NewTaskButton({ onClick }: ButtonProps) {
return (
<div>
    <buttonclassName="btn btn-accent btn-circle font-extrabold text-xl w-15 h-15"onClick={onClick}>+</button>
</div>);}

My tsconfig is this:
{   "compilerOptions": {     "lib": [       "dom",       "dom.iterable",       "esnext"     ],     "allowJs": true,     "skipLibCheck": true,     "strict": true,     "noEmit": true,     "esModuleInterop": true,     "module": "esnext",     "moduleResolution": "bundler",     "resolveJsonModule": true,     "isolatedModules": true,     "jsx": "preserve",     "incremental": true,     "plugins": [       {         "name": "next"       }     ],     "paths": {       "@/*": [         "./src/*"       ]     }   },   "exclude": [     "node_modules"   ],   "include": [     "next-env.d.ts",     "**/*.ts",     "**/*.tsx",     ".next/types/**/*.ts"   ] } 

and if I go to .next folder "/src/app/components/button/addNew/page.ts" there is a error on this line
// Check the prop type of the entry function 
checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()

I tried delete typescript cache, reinstalling node_modules, deleting .next folder, moving the interface to another file and then import, I also tried to use type any.

Solved:
I just have using page.tsx for each component and Next was adding that to the app router, I rename the components like src/app/components/addNew/page.tsx to src/app/components/addNew/addNew.tsx and that solved the problem.

Solved: I just have using page.tsx for each component and Next was adding that to the app router, I rename the components like src/app/components/addNew/page.tsx to src/app/components/addNew/addNew.tsx and that solved the problem
